# Como converter string (em português) em data?

Tags: string, r, data

Tenho um `data.frame` com uma coluna (mes) que representa o mês e o ano de cada observação que está em forma de string. Eu queria modificá-la para data para poder usar o proc no excel com data. Como posso fazê-la?

```
          mes                   Sub_item Brasil Brasilia.DF Goiania.GO Campo_Grande.MS Salvador.BA Fortaleza.CE
1  junho 2017    3103.Cama, mesa e banho  -0.73       -0.50      -0.88           -3.43       -3.37        -1.54
2   maio 2017    3103.Cama, mesa e banho  -0.42       -1.75       0.90           -3.51        1.88        -1.71
3  junho 2017       4101.Roupa masculina   0.39        0.73      -1.74            0.54        1.87        -2.00
4   maio 2017       4101.Roupa masculina   0.98       -0.57      -0.61            1.02        1.72         1.06
5  junho 2017        4102.Roupa feminina   0.21       -0.15      -0.25            1.42       -0.12         1.01
6   maio 2017        4102.Roupa feminina   1.10        0.69       0.43           -1.23        0.56         0.59
7  junho 2017        4103.Roupa infantil   0.51        1.01       0.49           -1.14        0.72        -0.28
8   maio 2017        4103.Roupa infantil   1.33        0.08       0.33            2.72        0.59        -0.41
9  junho 2017 4201.Calcados e acessorios   0.05        0.48      -0.69            0.12        1.14         0.19
10  maio 2017 4201.Calcados e acessorios   0.85        0.16       0.13            0.53        1.25         1.07
11 junho 2017    4301.Joias e bijuterias  -0.28       -1.42       0.27            0.96        0.40        -0.82
12  maio 2017    4301.Joias e bijuterias   0.49        1.67      -0.66           -0.74       -1.78        -2.26
13 junho 2017   4401.Tecidos e armarinho   0.36       -0.46       2.50           -0.68       -0.76         2.61
14  maio 2017   4401.Tecidos e armarinho   0.30       -0.93       1.06            0.29        1.11         0.39
```

Tentei utilizar algumas funções como `str_replace`, `as.Date`. Pensei em criar uma função que alteraria cada string "mês ano" para um formato data (infelizmente não consegui reproduzir).
Será que vocês tem alguma ideia? Valeu!

Comment: Para usar `as.Date` deve primeiro escolher um dia para a data, geralmente o dia `1`. Assim: `as.Date(paste("1", dados$mes), "%d %B %Y")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Criei o seguinte banco para usar como exemplo

```
dados <- data.frame(
  mes = c("junho 2017", "maio 2017", "junho 2017",
          "maio 2017", "junho 2017", "maio 2017",
          "junho 2017", "maio 2017", "junho 2017",
          "maio 2017", "junho 2017", "maio 2017"),
  x = rnorm(12)
)
dados$mes <- as.character(dados$mes)
```

Depois com o pacote `stringr` separei a variável `mes` em mês e ano, e o pacote `zoo` para transformar essas duas informações em uma única em formato de data

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
dados %>% 
  mutate(Data = as.yearmon(paste(word(mes), word(mes, -4))))
```

Na verdade, nem é necessária a separação da variável `mes` para usar a função `as.yearmon`. O código fica então

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
dados %>% 
  mutate(Data = as.yearmon(mes))
```

Comment: Amigo, duas coisas que não entendi: 1. pq você criou uma coluna com distribuição normal no data frame dados? 2. caso eu use a minha coluna já "mes" do meu data frame, o resultado será equivalente?

Comment: Danilo, eu criei uma variável com distribuição normal, só pra criar um data.frame de exemplo, tanto que eu nem utilizo a mesma. E quanto à segunda pergunta, utilizando o código `dados %>% mutate(Data = as.yearmon(mes))` creio que você obterá o resultado esperado. Só não esqueça de carregar os pacotes necessários (`dplyr` e `zoo`)

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Pensei numa alternativa não muito elegante, mas funciona.

```
vari <- c("junho 2009", "maio 2090", "outubro 1096", "junho 2509", "maio 2340", "abril 1342")
vari <- gsub("abril ", "04/", vari)
vari <- gsub("maio ", "05/", vari)
vari <- gsub("junho ", "06/", vari)
vari <- gsub("outubro ", "10/", vari)
```

use a função **gsub()**, ela substitui uma palavra ou numero que você quer por outra coisa que você queira.

Se eu entendi, você queria transformar em uma data numérica.